# Creating player boundaries in Javascript

Tags: javascript, 2d, 2d-games

I am currently facing an issue where without setting boundaries my player or otherwise referred to as cannon is allowed to move off the screen. I have tried implementing some boundaries but I am unable to figure out the logic and it currently does not work.

To clarify I'm looking to make it so once the cannon reaches the wall on either side (It can only move left to right) it is not allowed to exceed the boundaries of the game.

my current boundaries function.

```
function playerBounds() {
    //This will check the position of the spaceship and if it hits the boundaries of the canvas will not let it go further.

    if (spaceShip.x < 0) {
        spaceShip.x = 0;
    }
    else if (spaceShip.x > canvas.width || spaceShip.x < canvas.width  ) {
        spaceship.x = canvas.wdith - spaceShip.width;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is the logic in this statement

```
    else if (spaceShip.x > canvas.width || spaceShip.x < canvas.width  ) {
         spaceship.x = canvas.wdith - spaceShip.width;
    }
```

So let's say your canvas is 100px wide. If the ship's `x` position is at `100`, by default that's the lefthand side of an image to draw on the canvas (unless you've got some code to change its anchor point to the middle of it or something). See [MDN's page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage%28%29) for more info. So the canvas will start drawing to the right from that point, and go 18px, meaning the ship will be drawn from 100-118px, which would be offscreen.

Also, you say the width of the spaceship is 18, and I'm going to assume your canvas is wider than 18px, so the second part of that or statement, `spaceShip.x < canvas.width`, evaluated as `18 < 100` in the example, will always be true and thus unnecessary for a logical or. As a nasty side effect, it will also always snap your ship to the right side of the screen since it's always true.

The solution could be something like:

```
// outside of playerBounds function
// stored in a variable so this doesn't have to be recalculated every time
var rightBorder = canvas.width - spaceShip.width;

function playerBounds() {
    if (spaceShip.x < 0) {
        spaceShip.x = 0;
    }

    if (spaceShip.x > rightBorder) {
        spaceship.x = rightBorder;
    }
}
```

One more thing, you declare `var Time;` at the top, but you reference `time` everywhere else, just in case that was an accident.

Comment: Thanks for your Input, On trying your solution it fixes the problem of there being a crazy jump due to my logical statement before, But it still lets the player go off screen only on the right.

Comment: Updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Q4U2w/3/ A couple fixes (I commented them), the main thing was a typo in that second if. spaceShip vs. spaceship. I also noticed that in a couple places you had an assignment operator (=) instead of an equality operator (===).

Comment: Great! Changing over from Vb.net to Javascript has been really confusing and sometimes I just forget the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

```
else if (spaceShip.x > canvas.width || spaceShip.x < canvas.width  ) {
    spaceship.x = canvas.wdith - spaceShip.width;
}
```

1. `spaceShip.x > canvas.width || spaceShip.x < canvas.width` will
   always evaluate to true (unless `spaceShip.x` is equal to
   `canvas.width`), so your spaceship will effectively be locked in one position
   forever.
2. You have a typo in your assignment: `canvas.wdith` should be
   `canvas.width`

You need to adjust your conditional so that it only catches the case where the spaceship goes off the right edge of the canvas. It looks like you're on the right track, though.

Comment: Thanks! I have corrected that typo though it still doesn't correct my overall issue.

Comment: Did you also fix the else part? You need to remove the < check - it looks like it should work after that.

Comment: I figured it all out after prokopcm's answer, I was heading into the problem with the wrong mindset completely. Thank anyways.